# Why so strange behaviour when using "require" in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

When I import ClassA inside ClassB, and then import ClassA inside ClassB, the imported ClassA is an empty Object. To demonstrate, I have these 3 files:

**ClassA.js**

```js
const ClassB = require('./ClassB');

class ClassA {
    static test() {
        ClassB.test();
    }
}

module.exports = ClassA;
```

**ClassB.js**

```js
const ClassA = require('./ClassA');

class ClassB {
    static test() {
        console.log('ClassA.test', ClassA.test);
    }
}

module.exports = ClassB;
```

**index.js**

```js
const ClassA = require('./ClassA');

ClassA.test();
```

When I run `node index.js`, I expect to see `ClassA.test function` in console, but it outputs `ClassA.test undefined` instead. Is it some undocumented thing, or it's a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. The solution is to have a third class that will require both and use whatever code you have from `ClassA` in `ClassB` and the other way around.

```
const ClassA = require('./ClassA');
const ClassB = require('./ClassB');

class ClassC {
    static test() {
        ClassA.test();
        ClassB.test();
    }
}
```

> When I run node index.js, I expect to see ClassA.test function in
>   console, but it outputs ClassA.test undefined instead. Is it some
>   undocumented thing, or it's a bug?

No, it's not a bug, and it's not undocumented.

You can read more here on how it's handled: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

---

You can also do a lazy load, and will solve your issues for this particular case. But in most cases, circular references are a symptom of poorly written code.

```
class ClassB {
    static test() {
        const ClassA = require('./ClassA')
        console.log('ClassA.test', ClassA.test);
    }
}

module.exports = ClassB;
```

Comment: Yeah, using `const ClassA = require('./ClassA')` inside the `test()` method — that was exactly how I fixed it some time ago. Just was interested, why it happens.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing when you first encounter the error, but it makes sense though :). Glad to help.

Comment: I just realized why I was asking if it's undocumented or it's a bug: NodeJS usually is very generous for showing warnings/errors, but it keeps silence when circular dependency is happening. It just provides a damaged object without saying anything which is a bit unexpected behavior.

Comment: I agree about that, a warning would definitely be something positive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency, so Node can't know for certain which module's top-level code should run first - *one* of the modules needs to have its top-level code run first so that something should be exported so that the other module can import it via `require`. But if both depend on the other, then the first one that runs will have its `require` call to the other resolve to `undefined`.

The best solution would be to refactor it to avoid the circular dependency.