# TypeError: function x is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, typeerror, backend

I've defined the following function:

```
 const findSocketForUser = userId => {
  console.log("IM HERE ");
  const userSocketId = socketToUserMap[userId].socketId;
  console.log(userSocketId);
  return connections.find(x => x.id == userSocketId);
};
```

Next, I export the function here:

```
module.exports = {
  io,
  ...,
  findSocketForUser,
  ...
};
```

I import it in another file here:

```
const { findSocketForUser, io } = require("./../../socket");
```

and I try and use it as follows:

```
const newFunction = id => {
  Model1.findOne({
    where: {
      id: id
    },
    include: [{ model: Model2 }]
  })
    .then(result => {
      if (
        ...
      ) {
        Model1.update(
          {
            ...
          },
          { where: { id: id } }
        )
          .then(_ => {
            Model3.create({
              ...,
            })
              .then(_ => {
                newFunction2(
                  result.field1.field2,
                  id,
                  result.winner,
                  result.field3
                );
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        console.log("err");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

where `newFunction2` is:

```
const newFunction2 = (field1, field2, field3, field4) => {

  if (field1) {
    const socket = findSocketForUser(field1);

    ...
  }
};
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: findSocketForUser is not a function
    at newFunction2 (/...:71:20)
```

I also notice the `console.log` inside `findSocketForUser` is never executed. I ensured that the path is correct for the import, there is no typo's in the function name and the variables passed into `newFunction2` are all not-null. What is the issue?

UPDATE:

```
const {
  Model1,
  Model2,
  Model3
} = require("../../../db/sequelize");

const { findSocketForUser, io } = require("./../../socket");
const {
  MESSAGE1,
  MESSAGE2
} = require("./../../messages");
```

Comment: `console.log(findSocketForUser)` right after you required it. Show the output

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande it logs undefined

Comment: Now: `console.log(require("./../../socket"))` and update the question with all the code of both files, I need to see the requires you're doing.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande it logs {}

Comment: I know your issue, update the question with the code, so I can know for sure.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I've updated the question with the requires

Comment: No, you're missing the requires from `socket.js` file too, and I need to see the whole `socket.js` file.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I rather not post the whole code as I carry out user auth in that file - if you think you know what the issue is could you suggest a solution and then I can try it?

Comment: You either have a ciruclar reference or you're incorrectly exporting the variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449847/why-so-strange-behaviour-when-using-require-in-nodejs/59449870#59449870

Comment: So in `socket.js` I have `const {
  newFunction
} = require("./...");` which is the function in the question...would this cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. You are requiring file A in file B and the other way around. That's why when you use `require` you get `{}`.

The easiest solution is to break the circular reference with a third file.

Check this question too: [Why so strange behaviour when using "require" in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449847/why-so-strange-behaviour-when-using-require-in-nodejs/59449870#59449870)